# same css class is giving me two different colors of text

Tags: html, css

Trying to learn this stuff and just as I thought I was getting a grasp on it this problem pops up.
I have two buttons using the same class but the color of the text is different in each button

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3GUO.png)

```css
.button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: black;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #000;
}

.button a:hover {
  background-color: orange;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="button"><a href="https://twitter.com/*hidden*">Find me on <img width="50" alt="Twitter" src="images/twitter.png" /></a></button>
  <button class="button"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/*hidden*">Find me on <img width="50" alt="Twitter" src="images/twitter.png" /></a></button>
</div>
```

The Twitter button **"Find me on"** text is black as designed, but the Facebook button the **"Find me on"** text is white. What am I missing here? (I have tried it with just links, no HTML button, the color difference remains.)

Comment: Looks the same to me

Comment: In the snippet both of the look exactly the same. Updating your post with a screenshot might help us help you.

Comment: An `a` tag inside of a `button` is invalid HTML. Style the `a` tag with your `.button` properties. Also, both links have black text.

Comment: check carefully if you're not missing something in you code but here in the snippet both button are the same

Comment: @disinfor, I was unsure of using an a tag in a button element so I tried it by just styling the a tag as a button with the same results. Will go over that again and check for typos

Answer (score 0):

You are referring a:visited but not .button a:visited

Therefor I „think“ the different color you see is the browser visited color and not what you defined.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, found the stupid mistake. I noticed on inspection that the link color was being inherited from my footer. I apparently managed to quote out a closing div at the bottom of my page and somehow that I still don't understand the css for my footer links was overriding my button class. That makes sense to me, but I still can't figure why it only affected one button. With the div properly closed everything is good.